# Import PDF to Excel

Tags: excel, pdf, search, import

I have a program that I use to search for Excel sheets and import them into an Excel workbook.
Wondering if I can use the same code, with some modifications to search for PDF's in a folder and import them into an Excel workbook.

Sub Merge_Excel_Files_Created_By_CMM()
Dim fnameList, fnameCurFile As Variant
Dim countFiles, countSheets As Integer
Dim wksCurSheet As Worksheet
Dim wbkCurBook, wbkSrcBook As Workbook
ChDrive "I"
ChDir "I:\Quality\CMM Data"
Dim s As Range
Set s = Selection
fnameList = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Workbooks (*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm),*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm", Title:="Choose Excel files to merge", MultiSelect:=True)

```
If (vbBoolean <> VarType(fnameList)) Then

    If (UBound(fnameList) > 0) Then
        countFiles = 0
        countSheets = 0

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

        Set wbkCurBook = ActiveWorkbook

        For Each fnameCurFile In fnameList
            countFiles = countFiles + 1

            Set wbkSrcBook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fnameCurFile)

            For Each wksCurSheet In wbkSrcBook.Sheets
                countSheets = countSheets + 1
                wksCurSheet.Copy after:=wbkCurBook.Sheets(wbkCurBook.Sheets.Count)
            Next

            wbkSrcBook.Close SaveChanges:=False

        Next

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

        MsgBox "Processed " & countFiles & " files" & vbCrLf & "Merged " & countSheets & " worksheets", Title:="Merge Excel files"
    End If

Else
    MsgBox "No files selected", Title:="Merge Excel files"
End If
 s.Parent.Activate
 s.Select
```

End Sub

Comment: Have you researched the `Dir` function yet?

Comment: New to coding, not sure what I would need to do.